# Atom throws a crash message, but runs normally

Tags: 20.04, crash, atom

Having fed up with the startup slowness of the Atom editor which was installed as a snap by default, I removed the snap version and reinstalled Atom editor as described in https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/.

Now, each time I start the Atom editor, the following six lines are thrown to `syslog`:

```
.. kernel: [ 1637.277663] SGI_video_sync[8658]: segfault at e6 ip 000055acca0e26e2 sp 00007ffa61aec6c0 error 6 in atom[55acc7172000+5024000]
.. kernel: [ 1637.277683] Code: e8 43 00 00 00 4c 89 f7 e8 db 01 00 00 41 8b 46 10 41 8b 4e 18 c1 e0 0c 25 00 f0 0f 00 c1 e1 14 81 e1 00 00 f0 0f 09 c1 09 d9 <c6> 01 00 81 e3 ff 0f 00 00 c6 03 00 bf 01 00 00 00 e8 88 ec 0a 02
.. kernel: [ 1637.530847] SGI_video_sync[8679]: segfault at e6 ip 000055986171a6e2 sp 00007efca0c186c0 error 6 in atom[55985e7aa000+5024000]
.. kernel: [ 1637.530853] Code: e8 43 00 00 00 4c 89 f7 e8 db 01 00 00 41 8b 46 10 41 8b 4e 18 c1 e0 0c 25 00 f0 0f 00 c1 e1 14 81 e1 00 00 f0 0f 09 c1 09 d9 <c6> 01 00 81 e3 ff 0f 00 00 c6 03 00 bf 01 00 00 00 e8 88 ec 0a 02
.. kernel: [ 1637.781350] SGI_video_sync[8713]: segfault at e6 ip 000055e348cb76e2 sp 00007fc8405646c0 error 6 in atom[55e345d47000+5024000]
.. kernel: [ 1637.781355] Code: e8 43 00 00 00 4c 89 f7 e8 db 01 00 00 41 8b 46 10 41 8b 4e 18 c1 e0 0c 25 00 f0 0f 00 c1 e1 14 81 e1 00 00 f0 0f 09 c1 09 d9 <c6> 01 00 81 e3 ff 0f 00 00 c6 03 00 bf 01 00 00 00 e8 88 ec 0a 02
```

Besides this, Atom editor works with no problem. I am not expert on this, but maybe some thread of `atom` crashes only, without affecting the main window.

It does not make any difference whether I start `atom` normally or from command line in ***safe mode***. If this is the first time Atom editor is being started after a new desktop logon, sometimes, Ubuntu tries to create and send a "crash report" also.

- System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 (fully up-to-date)
- Atom: 1.50.0 (installed from https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ sources as described above)
- NVIDIA proprietary driver version 440

These messages do *not* appear in syslog for the time period I used the "snap" version. They started appearing after I installed the normal (.deb) version of `atom`.

Any help to pinpoint the problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: After atom was updated to 1.52.0 lately, this problem seems to have been gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. There is an update for Atom that was released today (2020-09-09). It's now version 1.51.0 and the issue is fixed.

Comment: I updated to 1.51.0 today. And, although Ubuntu no longer tries to create and send a "crash report", the errors (six lines) thrown to `syslog` are still there. Can you monitor your `syslog` during `atom` startup and verify this? Also: Have you switched to normal package installation of `atom` from snap installation like me?

Comment: Yes, it was first installed with snap. Then I switched to the official version.

Just watched syslog. You are right, the same lines are also printed on my computer although no crash report is displayed anymore.

I still have one suspicion: I first encountered the error when I installed a new graphics card and used the proprietary nvidia driver. In the Ubuntu crash report, an nvidia module could also be seen in the stack trace. Do you also use the nvidia proprietary driver or was that just a random dependency for me?

Comment: Yes. I am using *NVIDIA proprietary driver version 440*. I looked at the old `syslog`s and I didn't see these messages. These messages started appearing at September 6 which is the date I installed the "normal" (.deb) `atom` package.

Comment: I also use the same version (440). Guess what: I reset the driver to standard (nouveau) as a test. The error messages no longer appear. Unfortunately, this isn't a permanent solution for me, I need the proprietary driver :/

Comment: Today I updated to `nvidia-driver-450 (proprietary, tested)` version. But, the messages in the `syslog` file persist. Atom version is 1.51.0. FYI.

Comment: Same here. In addition, the Ubuntu Crash Reporter reappears. I will soon reinstall my system and then install Atom directly via the official way without installing it with snap beforehand. Let's see if the error then occurs.

Comment: Waiting for your experiences after you have done the re-installation...

Comment: Sorry for being late! It didn't changed anything. But: it seems to be fixed. Atom 1.53.0 / Nvidia driver 455 (prop./tested). There are no more Issues in syslog for me. Don't know if it was the driver update or the atom update which fixed it.